# Preview doesn't open pdf tabs in same window after updating to Monterey

Tags: pdf, preview

I updated from Big Sur to Monterey yesterday on my M1 Air but seem to have lost the option to open multiple pdfs in same window using Preview.
Here are the settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what the exact choices were under Big Sur but, as an option, you can merge the pdf windows after opening them so that they appear in the same window but under different tabs in Monterey. To do that, go to Window -> Merge All Windows while in Preview.

Answer (score 2):

From the official user guide at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvw1085/mac

> Note: To open multiple PDFs in the same window, go to System Preferences > General , then choose Always from the “Prefer tabs when opening documents” pop-up menu. See [Change how folders open in the Finder on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1032).